# Azure Django App has SECRET_KEY Exception

Tags: django, azure, settings, secret-key

I deployed my django web app on azure using GitHub, but the error I'm getting is:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

My settings.py file is

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS')


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
    "C:/Users/ande/Documents/FC_Database/FC_Database/frontend/templates/frontend/index.html"
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'SLAR',
    'import_export',
    'rest_framework',
    'frontend'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'FC_Database.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'FC_Database.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
        'PORT': 3306,
        'HOST': os.getenv('HOST')
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I added the secret key and the other database settings in Azure's application settings for security reasons, but its still not working.
[image]
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to retrieve the contents of environment variables using the os.environ dictionary, where the key is the name of the variable you are trying to get the contents of.

Here is part of the code you can use to retrieve environment variables from Azure WebApp

```
import os
...
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

Comment: It's saying that Environ object is not callable

Comment: Could you please try  commands - 
print os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') and
print os.environ['SECRET_KEY']